# Codeigniter ajax pass variable class

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, variables

My AJAX in view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){       

    $('.calendar .day').click(function(){

      var day_data= $(this).find('.content').html();

      if($(this).find('.content').html()!=null){


        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('calendar/pass_name')?>/",
            method:"POST",
            data:day_data,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        })
```

My controller

```
   function pass_name(){

    $name=$this->input->post('.calendar .day');
    echo $name;

    return $this->load->model('calendar_model')->get_description($name);
}
```

My model

```
function get_description($name){

    $query=$this->db->select('description')->from('calendar')->where('name'==$name);

    return $query;

}
```

What I would like to do is pass this variable through ajax, run a db query and return the result in a popup box.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: You need to echo your results : ```echo(json_encode($this->load->model('calendar_model')->get_description($name)));```. Try this in controller function and check console for output.

Comment: Also, you misunderstood with the concept of sending post data through ajax, you need to send it like ```data : { "varname" : value };``` and accept in controller like ``` $varname = $this->input->post("varname");```

Comment: what you want to pass in controller??

Comment: I made the changes in the AJAX -> data:{'day_data':day_data}, and in my controller. I am getting this inside the popup: {"dbdriver":"mysqli","_escape_char":"`","_like_escape_str":"","_like_escape_chr":"","... and it goes on....

Comment: @HarshPanchal I want to pass the variable I got by clicking on a calendar day (day_data), then call the model function from my controller which runs the sql query. Return then the result query in a popup. Just want to create an event calendar and when the user clicks on a day, return the event description in a popup.

Comment: means you say that how can i get response from controller ???. am i right??

Comment: I suppose so, I am positive the function in the model is correct to begin with, so how can I get the result from my controller?

Comment: Use type instead of method

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){       

$('.calendar .day').click(function(){

  var day_data= $(this).find('.content').html();

  if($(this).find('.content').html()!=null){


    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('calendar/pass_name')?>/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{day_data:day_data},
        success:function(data){
           if(data==1)
           {
              $('#response').html(data);
           }
        }
    })
 </script>
```

Changer IN Your Controller

```
function pass_name()
{

    $name=$this->input->post('day_data');

    if($this->load->model('calendar_model')->get_description($name)==TRUE)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it seems the data is empty, nothing is displayed in the popup box. :/

Comment: check in alert at response time. what output display in alert

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I added the get() function in my model query and it worked. This is an example of the display: {"calendar":[{"description":"Test area\r\nwww.google.com"}]} I wonder if I can make it better by displaying just the value "test area..." etc.

Comment: Most Welcome @Marilena